# show that closure of $c_{00}$ is $c_{0}$ in $\ell$-infinity

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x=(x(1),x(2),…,x(n),…) \in c_0$.

So for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x(n)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Now for all $n \geq n_0$ , $||x_n − x||_\infty = \sup \{|x(m)|: m \geq n_0 \} \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$.

I have a doubt that regarding the last line.

That is, how can we say that
                                                                         $$\sup \{ |x(n+1)|, |x(n+2)|, ......... \} = \sup \{ |x(m)|:m > n \} \to 0$$ as $m \to \infty$ ?
                                                                           (because we dont know the supremum of this set (i.e. $\sup \{ |x(m)|:m>n \}$ ), it can                                                                         be infinity also).

*So how can we say that $\sup \{ |x(m)|:m>n \} \to 0$ ?*
*What makes it possible?*

Comment: What  are   $c_0$  and  $c_{00}$  $?$

Comment: C_{0} is the sequences converging to 0 and in c_{00}  the elements are sequences of scalars having only a finite number of non zero terms

Comment: What  if  we  take  this  sequence  in  $c_{00}$  : $\{x_n\}$  s.t  $x_n=(1,1/2,1/3,....,1/n,0,0,0,....0,0...)$  then  the  sequence  converges  to $x=(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,......,1/n,1/(n+1),......)$  and  not  to  $0=(0,0,0,0,....,0...)$  so  this  sequence  of  $c_{00}$  is  not  in  $c_0$ . But  closure  of  $c_{00}$  is  supposed  to  contain   $c_{00}$ .

Comment: Also  the  sequence  in  $c_{00}$  s.t  $x_n$  has  $1$'s  in  first  $n$  co-ordinates  and  $0$'s  elsewhere  then  this  sequence  does  not  converge  at all  so  this  $\{x_n \}$  is  also  not  in  $c_0$ .

Answer (score 1):

Let $ε>0$, because $x(n)$ converges to $0$ we have that there exists a $ξ \in \Bbb N$ so that for every $n>ξ$, $|x(n)|<ε$ if $m>n>ξ$ ($m$ goes to infinity) then $|x(m)|<ε$ and so $sup|x(m)| \le ε$ for $m>n$. Then we send $ε$ to zero and we have it!